# Multiple apps in our parse-server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, parse-platform

Given that there's a solution for running multiple apps (here: https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/1979)  in one parse-server, what would be the approach to migrate existing data from multiple parse servers while keeping the ids and other relations, etc. intact?

Comment: backup your old mongodb and migrate the new data, then connect your new parse server to the new db, whats the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must not run multiple apps on parse-server as the parse instance which is used in parse server is a singleton class.